# Local subdomain rerouting to XAMPP default page

Tags: apache, google-chrome, dns, xampp

I am running into a strange issue with XAMPP and Chrome. I have made several subdomains on localhost over the years (foo.localhost, bar.localhost, etc.) *These have been working fine on all browsers thus far*. My HOST file is properly configured with no recent changes.

I added these subdomains this way:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/xampp/htdocs/foo"
    ServerName foo.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And in Hosts I put:

```
127.0.0.1 foo.localhost
```

The exact behavior is this. On Firefox I type in `http://foo.localhost/bar/bat` and I get the intended resource from Apache on XAMPP. I type in the exact same address on Chrome and I get redirected to `http://foo.localhost/xampp/`.

The unique point here is that Firefox does work, Chrome does not.

Server access logs don't show anything strange.

I can't figure this out. Here are my system details:

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- Firefox 38.0.5
- Chrome 43.0.2357.130 m

If anyone has any ideas please feel free to share :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added the IPv6 equivalent in the host file and all worked henceforth. There's no place like `::1`